# How to check UIButton position in a ScrollView?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have a UIButton in a ScrollView. This button is hided by the NavigationBar, so it is visible only when the user drag down the ScrollView. I want to check the position of the UIButton, and if the y position is <= 41 then i want to display an Alert
How can I make this?
Thanks!! Bye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position of the yButton never changes (As in the frame of the yButton is the same in the scroll view).  What does change is the `contentOffset` property of the `UIScrollView`. So you can implement the delegate method `– scrollViewDidScroll:` which can implement the logic to determine if the button is in your desired state.